# How to solve "No module named 'cStringIO'" when importing the logging module in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run the following script, named `msgpack_checker.py`, in Python 3:

```
import msgpack
from faker import Faker
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

fake = Faker()
fake.seed(0)

data_file = "my_log.log"

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = RotatingFileHandler(data_file, maxBytes=2000, backupCount=10)
handler.terminator = ""         # Suppress the newline character (only works in Python 3)
logger.addHandler(handler)

fake_dicts = [{'name': fake.name()} for _ in range(100)]

for item in fake_dicts:
    dump_string = msgpack.packb(item)
    # print dump_string
    logger.debug(dump_string)

unpacker = msgpack.Unpacker(open(data_file))

print("Printing unpacked contents:")
for unpacked in unpacker:
    print(unpacked)
```

when I run it with Python 2, it prints the following output:

```
Printing unpacked contents:
{'name': 'Joshua Carter'}
10
{'name': 'David Williams'}
10
{'name': 'Joseph Jones'}
10
{'name': 'Gary Perry'}
10
{'name': 'Terry Wells'}
10
{'name': 'Vanessa Cooper'}
10
{'name': 'Michael Simmons'}
10
{'name': 'Nicholas Kline'}
10
{'name': 'Lori Bennett'}
10
```

The numbers "10" I believe come from the logger, and should be removed in Python 3 by the `handler.terminator = ""` command. However, if I try to run the script using `python3 msgpack_checker.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "msgpack_checker.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/home/kurt/Documents/Scratch/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref
ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'
```

Apparently the `logging` module tries to import `cStringIO` directly, which no longer exists in Python 3. I've seen fixes which involve importing `StringIO` from `io` instead of `StringIO`, but I not sure they would work here. Any suggestions on how to get this script to work in Python 3?

Comment: But that seems to be your code in `logging/__init__.py`. If you want it to work in Python 3, you'll need to use the right imports for that version.

Comment: It looks like you have *your own module* called `logging` which is what's getting imported. I would suggest renaming that folder to something else.

Comment: So where is your `logging` package coming from? That's **not** the standard library package. You are masking it with something else. Move that 'something else' aside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in several comments, I accidentally left a directory `logging` in the same directory which is what the error message refers to. After removing that directory, I get a different error message,

```
Printing unpacked contents:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "msgpack_checker.py", line 27, in <module>
    for unpacked in unpacker:
  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 459, in msgpack._unpacker.Unpacker.__next__ (msgpack/_unpacker.cpp:459)
  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 380, in msgpack._unpacker.Unpacker._unpack (msgpack/_unpacker.cpp:380)
  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 370, in msgpack._unpacker.Unpacker.read_from_file (msgpack/_unpacker.cpp:370)
TypeError: expected bytes, str found
```

but that is a separate issue; at least the importing of `logging` was successful.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question rather than adding it as an answer here or trying to modify your existing question.

Comment: And the solution to the new error is to open the file in binary mode instead: `open(data_file, 'b')`.